# Springでの、MultipartFileの非同期アップロード

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, java8, model-view-controller

同様の記事は多数見受けられましたが、一通り試して解決しなかったため、ご教授願います。

Spring4
Java8
WTPServer

を使用した環境での、input type="file"の非同期アップロードについてです。

一部では、「セキュリティー上の都合で、Ajaxでの送信はできない」とのコメントがありましたが、
少数派であったため、信ぴょう性にかけました。
form.submit()での送信は成功しているため、Springの設定等は省略します。

view.jsp

```
<input type="file" id="image_upload">
```

upload.js

```
$("#image_upload").change(function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    var file = $("#thumbnail_appender").prop("files")[0];
    var name = file.name;
    var size = file.size;

    fd.append("file", file);
    fd.append("name", name);
    fd.append("size", size);

    $.ajax({
        url: http://localhost:8080/upload,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data : fd,
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (callBack != null) {
                return callBack(textStatus);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

UploadController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="*/*")
public String thumbnailChange(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                              @RequestParam("size") long size, 
                              HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
        Part part = parts.iterator().next();
        File inputFile = (File) ReflectionUtils.select(ReflectionUtils.select(part, "fileItem"), "tempFile");
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);

        String[] nameSep = name.split("\\.");
        String outputFile = SAVE_DIRECTORY + name;

        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, nameSep[name.length() - 1], new File(outputFile));
        return outputFile.getName();
}
```

UploadControllerに

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile
```

を設定すると、「そんなパラメータ来てませんよ」となります。
HttpServletRequest内にはパラメータが入っているようですが、
ダンプしても肝心のバイナリデータがありませんでした。
アプリケーションコンテキスト内に.tmpというデータで仮保存されているようで、
ApplicationPart.fileItem.tempFileにフルパスの文字列がありました。
※そのパスが指すファイルはありませんでしたので、違うテストを行っている際に作られたものだと思いますが

画像のバイナリデータおよび、メタデータをサーバーサイドで処理したいのですが、
何か設定ミスがありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

質問に記載した実装では、ファイルのヘッダ情報のようなものは受信可能でしたが、バイナリデータ自体は送信されていませんでした。

コントローラ

```
@Controller
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024 * 1024, maxFileSize=10 * 1024 * 1024, maxRequestSize=10 * 1024 * 1024)
public class maintnanceController extends CommonsExceptionHandler {
```

とすることで、受信することができました。